# IdeaPad Slim 3 15IRU8 82X7CTO1WW ubuntu-22.04.3 LTS install failed

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, grub-efi, ideapad, ufs

I just bought this new IdeaPad Slim 3 15IRU8 (82X7CTO-1WW) laptop, with no OS and the following specs:

Core i3-1305U / 128GB UFS 3.1 on systemboard / Intel UHD Graphics / Intel SoC (System on Chip) platform / 8GB soldered RAM.

This laptop is intended for bedside internet/mail/light stuff and I don't want to keep Windows 11 (It's not even activated).

I failed to install Ubuntu, installed Windows 11 (no issue - updated the UEFI flash BIOS to LTCN27WW) then tried again with Ubuntu, with the same result, but I don't quite understand the issue:

Boot result:

[image: Boot result]

From what I read here, the ACPI error is just a warning.

I take it the issue could be:

- Boot args (cat/ proc/cmdline)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
- UUID=61365d15-0429-49df-93c7-ddd9bbebde80 does not exist

So I'm working on it, loading the "Try it" version.

By the way, when I boot with the USB drive trial, Ubuntu runs fine, everything works as with Windows 11 (well, I didn't try the fingerprint).

Here's a screenshot of GParted:

Windows 11 drive:

[image: w11 drive]

Ubuntu's drive:

[image: Ubuntu's drive]

At Lenovo's BIOS update's website there's also an Intel Management Engine 16.1 Firmware that's advised to update, but the readme says not to, unless you know why, and I don't, so I didn't.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you found a solution. I think [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) may have solved your problem with booting Ubuntu 22.04. Or may be not. Sometimes new computers have hardware that is not recognized by the older kernel used in the LTS version.

Comment: Thanks, user68186 : I'll give an update when I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I found out, there's a lot of things one can try.

Or, maybe the usb key (or the downloaded image) is corrupted.
I also read I could try with Ubuntu 23.04 (although it's not an LTS version).

And that's what I did : laptop got rid of Windows 11, Ubuntu 23.04 is running just fine (I kept trying and it seems 22.04 was the issue, not the iso nor the stick).

---

Addendum :
27c6:550a FingerPrint Driver for Linux is available at  :
[Goodix driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e14-gen-4-type-21eb-and-21ec/downloads/ds560884-goodix-fingerprint-driver-for-linux-thinkpad-e14-gen-4-e15-gen-4)

The procedure worked just fine for me ! (simply follow the Readme.txt)

Elle est pas belle la vie ?